# Visual Studio Code won't run my python code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am starting python with Visual Studio Code and am using Tkinter. When I run the lines of code in the shell it works, but it does nothing when I run my code in the editor.

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text='click me')
btn.pack()
```

[Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm0JK.png)

Comment: You missed a space in your import.

Comment: The expected result of running that code is to do nothing, other than maybe a momentary flash of a window.  You need `tk.mainloop()` at the end to keep the window open and interactable.

Comment: did you forget to say `tk.mainloop()` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you forget to say tk.mainloop() at the end? – Cool Cloud

Yes! thank you.

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text='click me')
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check which Python version/environment your vscode is targeting:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

If your vscode targets Python 2, then the package would be `Tkinter` (with an uppercase T).

If you're able to run it from another shell, then you must have it installed, but this is another problem that can come up... on Ubuntu for example you'd want to install `python3-tk` via apt (assuming you're running Python 3).

Comment: I'm running this from python3, which is what I want. And as you said, it works in the python shell, so I do not know why it doesn't wor in the editor.